# differentability from a functional inequality

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> Let $f$ be a non-negative continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ vanishing at $0$. If $f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ does not exceed $\frac{f(x)}{n}$ for any $n,x$ show that $f$ has a finite right-hand derivative at $0$.

Comment: Could you please tell us what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $n \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The inequality is only for positive integers n. This is an exercise in a book of Bourbaki and I have no idea how to get started. My guess is that the derivative must be infimum of f(x)/x over all x>0. There is also a hint which says the proof is by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let m and M be liminf and limsup of $f(x)/x$ as x tends to 0. If possible let $m<M$. Pick $\alpha$ between m and M. Then $f(a)<a\alpha$ for some a. By continuity $f(x)<x\alpha$ for all x in (a-r,a) for some r>0. If $0<x<r$ the interval ((a-r)/x,a/x) has length exceeding 1 and hence it contains an integer n. This gives $f(nx)<nx\alpha$. The hypothesis now gives nf(x)<$nx\alpha$ or f(x)<$x\alpha$. This holds for all x in (0,r) so $M\leq\alpha$, a contradiction.

Comment: +1. Nice proof.